# MAC filtering for DHCP3 server

Tags: networking, mac, dhcp

I am setting up a school network and i have an ubuntu 13.10 sever. I am looking for a way to deny all devices to get an ip, except for the devices which MAC address I specify in a certain list.

As I was browsing another server to see how that is configured, i saw an /etc/ethers. What is that all about?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: If you are referring to dhcpd, please give `man dhcpd.conf` a try. You should find all the information you need in there.  Look at the section ADDRESS POOLS in it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to  dhcpd.conf to ignore requests from a set of MAC addresses

```
class "deny" {
            match if substring(hardware,1,4) = 00:11:22:33;
    }


    pool {
            deny members of "deny";
            range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.254;
            }
```

Change the Mac and the range as your network fits .

**Hope it help you**